# Create dynamic page with php

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm writing a small routing system for a project. It's not perfect and it's a custom solution that will map the url to their templates if requested from the user. I want to generate a dynamic page based on an unique id for each event inserted inside the database from the user. So if the user request the event 1234 it will get a page with the event detail at the url `https://mysitedomain.com/event/1234`. I need to understand how to achieve this with my code, I'm using a front controller and red bean as ORM to access the database.
Here is the code of my router. Any suggestion will be appreciated. for now I'm only able to serve the templates.

```
<?php
namespace Router;

define('TEMPLATE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/assets/templates/');

class Route {

  private static $assets = ['bootstrap' => 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'jquery' => 'assets/js/jquery.min.js',
    'bootstrapjs' => 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  ];

    public static function init()
    {
      if( isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ){
        $requested_uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
          if( $requested_uri === '/' ){
            echo self::serveTemplate('index', self::$assets);
          }
          elseif( $requested_uri != '/' ){
            $requested_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            if( $requested_uri[1] === 'event' ){
              echo self::serveTemplate('event', self::$assets, ['event_id' => 001] );
            }
            else{
              echo self::serveTemplate($view, self::$assets);
            }
          }
      }
    }

    private static function serveTemplate(string $template, array $data, array $event_id = null)
    {
      if( !is_null($event_id) ){
        $data[] = $event_id;
        ob_start();
        extract($data);
        require_once TEMPLATE_PATH."$template.php";
        return ob_get_clean();
      }
      else{
        ob_start();
        extract($data);
        require_once TEMPLATE_PATH."$template.php";
        return ob_get_clean();
      }
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a router from scratch is a little complex, you have to play a lots with [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to accommodate various scenario of requested url and your router should handle HTTP methods like POST, GET, DELETE, PUT and PATCH.

You may want to use existing libraries like [Fast Route](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute), easy to use and it's simplicity could give you idea how it is created.

Comment: I'm working on this for learning more about the MVC pattern applied to PHP. I know about fast route, it will be the same of the concept I was working on?